# Angular 2: Trigger Interpolation From other Component not working

Tags: angular

I have two components, C1 and C2.
I want to trigger the interpolation in C2 when clicking a button in C1.

The interpolated value is defined in C2 as a public variable:

`public elementType: string = "test";`

C2 is defined in C1 as following:

```
import {PropertiesComponent} from "../properties/properties.component";
constructor(private propComp: PropertiesComponent) {}
setActive(model){console.log("test");
this.propComp.elementType = "updated value";}
```

The console log is triggered, but the interpolation is not.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the component like a service. So added it to the constructor and all.

You can pass the elementType from C2 to C1 as @Input() elementType and it will meet your expectation.

In C1

```
@Input() elementType;
setActive(model){
console.log("test");
this.elementType = "updated value";
}
```

Comment: I also tried with @Input() elementType: string = "test"; but that did not make any difference

Comment: not in C2 but in C1. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction is really good one. Please go thru' it for complete understanding.

Comment: Where does the link between this variable in C2 and C1 happen? Can you explain that?

Comment: I had edited my post and if you want the child changes to reach the parent, then use event emitting @Output() onSetActive = new EventEmitter<boolean>();  and emit this.onSetActive.emit(agreed);

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it using a service. I think thats the proper way!

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Angular services to refer the values set by C1 component inside C2 component.
Inject the Service in both the components.
Declare the variable `elementType` in your service. 
Set the variable `elementType` of service within component C1.
Now you can access it in component C2 via service instance.

If you dont like to use service, then you have to pass from C1 to C2 using `@Input()` and `@Output()` variables.

As @Padmapriya said, you cannot inject component like a service. Rather you can use component as a child component to exchange data.